# How to enter into "Full Screen Mode" in my Android App when pressed a toggle button to "ON"?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am new to Android Development. 
- My requirement is that :  My App should become full screen when i press the toggle button
  on my app to "ON".
- I did a lot of research and found that if we set the " View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY"
  the app turn into full screen and the it remains in full screen.
- I have three tabs( Home , Details , Speed) in my app and i have created three different
  layout files for each of the tabs.
- So, in "Home" tab's layout file : fragment_home i am writing the code as :

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private View mDecorView;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
                  mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY 
                      | View.INVISIBLE); 
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
            }
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

But i am getting error as "The method getWindow() is undefined for the type HomeFragment"
**getWindow() is a system method, even on the android developers site they are using it like this. Then why its not running for me. where is the problem in my code.
Please help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window is associated with Activity. Hence change :

```
mDecorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
```

to

```
mDecorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
```